# Update or broadcast variable in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am facing a problem in which i have to update a broadcasted map after certain time intervals.
I am able to do that when i am using spark streaming by creating a wrapper around my broadcast variable but that solution is not working in spark structured Streaming. Does anyone who know how to solve this.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried in spark streaming? AFIK, broadcast variables are immutable.

Comment: Yep , that's correct. I ended up using spark-streaming. Apparently it's not possible as of now in structured streaming.